# Is it appropriate to approve an edit that only adds a link to documentation?

Tags: discussion, review, edits, suggested-edits

I see that happen quite often on answers with code, and mostly to the official documentation of a function. I believe a comment would be better, but I'm not sure what the consensus here is.

Comment: If you don't find answers, which quote documentation to be helpful, you should downvote them.  Comments shouldn't be used to answer a question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If it actually helps the post, and the link *is* to the official documentation (not a SEO scraper that just copied it hoping to steal some search traffic), then it's fine - it actually improves the post.

Comments can be obliterated *at any time*, so don't use them to store lasting useful information, or expect useful information left in comments to surface above anything else (we hide some comments by default).

IOW: Don't use comments for anything other than discussing an edit you weren't comfortable making without prior collaboration. Anything else is subject to speedy removal.

Answer (score 9):

In general, I think a link to documentation, as long as it helps readers understand the question/answer more easily, will be an improvement to a post.

If the documentation link is important to the post then it does not belong in a comment.

At the same time I would not approve an out of context link to documentation.